# jQuery issue with PHP data and Highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm having an issue with the X axis data which is dynamic as it seems to use all the values in the first column.

I'm doing the below:

```
<div id="season_data_block" style="display: none;">
<?php
foreach($champ_name as $champ_id => $stat_value) {
    foreach ($stat_value as $cn => $cs) {
        if($champ_id != 0) {
            echo '"'.$cn.'",';
        }
    } 
}
?>
</div>
```

This is putting the PHP data into a hidden div. Then I am using jQuery to access the text from that div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var chart_data = $("#season_data_block").text();
    $('#stats_chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [chart_data]
        },
```

The issue I'm having is that when the data is inserted into the javascript xAxis, it shows all the php data on the first xAxis value then the rest is defaulted, like below.

First: "name 1","name 2","name 3",
Second: 2
Third: 3
Fourth 4

I want it to be

First: "name 1"
Second: "name 2"
Third: "name 3"

etc. Why is it doing that?

Thanks

Comment: How does your categories look like?

Comment: categories: ["name1","name2","name3"] etc. how its suppose to be, but only views it as one value rather than several

Comment: If your plot data only has 1 data point, then it will be like that I think. Each point has to correspond to a point on the X axis.

Comment: I think your categories looks like: `['"name1","name2","name3"']` - if  first label contains all names. Open you site and check source code.

Comment: Nope its pull through fine, just being read wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I turned my PHP data into another array and then json_encode() that array into a javascript array. Simple :)